# How to filter out partial match in an Excel row?

Tags: excel, aggregate

I have an Excel sheet with dates in the rows. A given month should be used only once in a row. How can I filter out, if there are two dates in the same row from the same month?

For example I have the following array, and I would like to have as a result, that there is a match in this row (2012-03).

```
2012-03-04  2012-02-05  2012-04-06  2012-03-07  2012-10-08  2012-11-09  2012-12-10
```

I have tried to combine aggregate and match functions, but I cannot find out how to do it properly.
One of my codes, of course it gave an error:

```
=aggregate(9,6,(MATCH("*"&LEFT(A8,7)&"*","*"&LEFT(b8,7)&"*",0), MATCH("*"&LEFT(b8,7)&"*","*"&LEFT(c8,7)&"*",0)))
```

Ok, now I have tried another way, and I could get a solution, but with a code which is like a km long...I have first created a new dataset, cutting down the days by using: ="*"&LEFT(A8,7)&"*"
Then I have compared all the cells in a given row of my new dataset. Could someone help me how to shorten the exact( ) parts? The aim is to compare all.

=if((or(exact(A2, B2), exact(A2,C2),exact(A2,D2),exact(A2,E2),exact(A2,F2),exact(A2,G2),exact(A2,H2),exact(A2,I2),exact(A2,J2),exact(A2,K2),exact(A2,L2),exact(A2,M2),exact(A2,N2),exact(A2,O2),exact(A2,P2),exact(A2,Q2),exact(A2,R2),exact(B2,C2),exact(B2,D2),exact(B2,E2),exact(B2,F2),exact(B2,G2),exact(B2,H2),exact(B2,I2),exact(B2,J2),exact(B2,K2),exact(B2,L2),exact(B2,M2),exact(B2,N2),exact(B2,O2),exact(B2,P2),exact(B2,Q2),exact(B2,R2),exact(C2,D2),exact(C2,E2),exact(C2,F2),exact(C2,G2),exact(C2,H2),exact(C2,I2),exact(C2,J2),exact(C2,K2),exact(C2,K2),exact(C2,L2),exact(C2,M2),exact(C2,N2),exact(C2,O2),exact(C2,P2),exact(C2,Q2),exact(C2,R2),exact(D2,E2),exact(D2,F2),exact(D2,G2),exact(D2,H2),exact(D2,I2),exact(D2,J2),exact(D2,K2),exact(D2,L2),exact(D2,M2),exact(D2,N2),exact(D2,O2),exact(D2,P2),exact(D2,Q2),exact(D2,R2),exact(E2,F2),exact(E2,G2),exact(E2,H2),exact(E2,I2),exact(E2,J2),exact(E2,K2),exact(E2,L2),exact(E2,M2),exact(E2,N2),exact(E2,O2),exact(E2,P2),exact(E2,Q2),exact(E2,R2),exact(F2,G2),exact(F2,H2),exact(F2,I2),exact(F2,J2),exact(F2,K2),exact(F2,L2),exact(F2,M2),exact(F2,N2),exact(F2,O2),exact(F2,P2),exact(F2,Q2),exact(F2,R2),exact(G2,H2),exact(G2,I2),exact(G2,J2),exact(G2,K2),exact(G2,L2),exact(G2,M2),exact(G2,N2),exact(G2,O2),exact(G2,P2),exact(G2,Q2),exact(G2,R2),exact(H2,I2),exact(H2,J2),exact(H2,K2),exact(H2,L2),exact(H2,M2),exact(H2,N2),exact(H2,O2),exact(H2,P2),exact(H2,Q2),exact(H2,R2),exact(I2,J2),exact(I2,K2),exact(I2,L2),exact(I2,M2),exact(I2,N2),exact(I2,O2),exact(I2,P2),exact(I2,Q2),exact(I2,R2),exact(J2,K2),exact(J2,L2),exact(J2,M2),exact(J2,N2),exact(J2,O2),exact(J2,P2),exact(J2,Q2),exact(J2,R2),exact(K2,L2),exact(K2,M2),exact(K2,N2),exact(K2,O2),exact(K2,P2),exact(K2,Q2),exact(K2,R2),exact(L2,M2),exact(L2,N2),exact(L2,O2),exact(L2,P2),exact(L2,Q2),exact(L2,R2),exact(M2,N2),exact(M2,O2),exact(M2,P2),exact(M2,Q2),exact(M2,R2),exact(N2,O2),exact(N2,P2),exact(N2,Q2),exact(N2,R2),exact(O2,P2),exact(O2,Q2),exact(O2,R2),exact(P2,Q2),exact(P2,R2),exact(Q2,R2))),"same month","ok")

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are your dates in YYYY-MM-DD format?

Comment: When you say "... two dates in the same row from the same month", do you also mean the same year? E.g.  `2012-03-04` and `2012-03-07` are the same month, but  `2013-03-04` and `2014-03-07` are different because the years are different.

Comment: @JGFMK, yes, exactly

Comment: @xidgel, yes indeed, tha years also have to be the same

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there is a better way, 
but this is how I'd tackle the problem based on my Excel knowledge:

1. Add data of dates above in cells `A1-G1`
2. On row below date add formulas for dates: `A2=DATE(A1)` ..... `G2=DATE(G1)`
3. At the end of the original row of dates add the numbers 1 thru 12:
    
   using formula cell `H1=1`, `I1=H1+1` ..... `S1=R1+1`
4. After the months on row 2:
   `H2=COUNTIF($A2:$G2,H1)` ..... `S2=COUNTIF($A2:$G2,S1)`
   Counting frequency for each of the 12 months
5. `T2=MAX(H2:S2)`
6. Then select on cell `T2`being more than `1`.

[Here it is as a Google sheet](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Yz6wDh7CUUhbmka8xST-9Nfuc73D_ywU/view?usp=sharing) (you can download it and open in Excel if you want)

[image: Formulas (1 of 3)]

[image: Formulas (2 of 3)]

[image: Formulas (3 of 3)]

[image: Data]

Comment: Thank you. As xidgel has highlighted, the years also have to be the same.
Plus, I am not sure how to handle it in a big datasheet, where I have 15 column and ~100 rows?

Comment: In that case you would have A2=YEAR(A1)*100 + MONTH(A1)...  But I see having months 1 thru 12 then becomes an issue.. Since you'd need to summarise the Years too. It almost then sounds more like a PIVOT table issue. Let me give it some thought...

Comment: BTW - This problem now seems more suited to SQL and SELECT DISTINCT syntax. Have you got the flexibility to map the spreadsheet to a database instead?

Comment: Unfortunately it has to stay in Excel. Now it is working with the added edition (see in my question). Do you eventually have any idea how to shorten the code?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with the operands you are using to add much on that. (aggregate/exact - some of the arguments you pass aren't very well documented in the help).

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kqsqLAhsdnrf1et0Q2HuHrkTGCcwJW63/view?usp=sharing Did some stuff using MIN/MINIF/SUMPRODUCT - not sure if it's any better for you - but it's another stab at it. Specifically look at Sheet 2. Download it into Excel to see SUMPRODUCT -Google Sheets uses something called arrayformula instead

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help. Assume that the range of dates is in `$A$1:$G$1`. Also assume that the entries are numerical dates; if they are instead text you can handle this by using the `DATEVALUE` function. Then we can get the years and months of the range with:

```
{=YEAR($A$1:$G$1)}
{=MONTH($A$1:$G$1))
```

This and all other formulas must be entered as **array formulas** (<kbd>Crtl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>).

We next convert back to a date, but use `1` for the day, so that all dates get shifted to the first day of the month (this means that any dates from the same month are shifted to the same date):

```
{=DATE(YEARS,MONTHS,1)}
```

We can produce an `NxN` comparison of the shifted dates by:

```
{=TRANSPOSE(SHIFTED_DATES)=SHIFTED_DATES}
```

We can count the number of `True`'s in this array by:

```
{=SUM(--(ARRAY))}
```

If there we no dates from the same month we'd expect this to sum to `N` because this method compare each date to itself as well as the other dates. The causes the `N` elements on the main diagonal of this array to be `True`. If any dates are in the same month off-diagonal elements will also be `True`. So to detect if there are dates from the same month we make the comparison:

```
{=SUM(--(ARRAY)) > N}
```

or more generally:

```
{=SUM(--(ARRAY)) > COUNT($A$1:$G$1)}
```

Rolling all of these up into one formula:

```
=IF(SUM(--(TRANSPOSE(DATE(YEAR($A$1:$G$1),MONTH($A$1:$G$1),1))=DATE(YEAR($A$1:$G$1),MONTH($A$1:$G$1),1)))>COUNT(DATE(YEAR($A$1:$G$1),MONTH($A$1:$G$1),1)),"same month","ok")
```

If your dates are in a range other than `$A$1:$G$1` then make the appropriate substitutions.

Hope that helps.